# Actionscript 3 $cinit Error

Tags: actionscript-3

When I run my program I get the following error (no compiler errors reported):

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property 20 not found on Number and there is no default value.
    at src.shared.campaign.ships::ShipClasses$cinit()
    at global$init()[docs\src\shared\campaign\ships\ShipClasses.as:4]
```

This is the first time I've encountered this error.  `ShipClasses.as` is a class definition with both static constants and methods.  The constants are arrays which contain `String` and `uint` datatypes as well as nested arrays. I just don't know where to start looking for the error.

Comment: Welcome to SO, a little bit of code of the affected area may help. Try to add code block to stacktraces and code (I wish I could but you can't suggest small edits like that)

Answer (score 0):

Though code would be helpful to pinpoint the exact issue. But, what the error is telling is that in line-4 of of ShipClasses.as you are accessing a property named '20' on an object which is of type `Number`. Since, `Number` doesn't have any such property, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had omitted a comma in a static constant definition of a nested array, thus the runtime error transforming an array element into a number property:

static const CONST:Array = [20, 16 [20, 18]];

Corrected code: static const CONST:Array = [20, 16, [20, 18]];

Of course, this is a simplified example of the issue.  The actual arrays were much larger and numbered about 40 definitions.  Thus it was difficult to recognize, especially since no line numbers are given when there is a $cinit runtime error.

Does anyone know how to find the line numbers in a case like this?